# How to exclude generated mocks from package coverage in Visual Studio Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm unit-testing a Golang project, via Visual Studio Code, and one of the dependencies I make use of is called [`mockery`](https://github.com/vektra/mockery/). It works by creating mocks of the target Golang interfaces, in the package they're found. As consequence, even though I could have sworn to test everything in said package, my test coverage is only at 58%. However, when I remove the mock (turns out that I didn't need it) from the package, my test coverage, sure as rain, shoots up to the 97.9% that I was expecting.

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio Code "hey, don't include mockery mocks (which start with `mock_`) in your package coverage calculations"?

Comment: Who voted to close this and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use mockery -inpkg and -testonly flags so generated mocks will go to the original package where interface is defined. Also generated files will have _test.go suffix so they will be ignored by the code coverage tool and by the compiler when you build your program.

Comment: I just ran it on an interface I just created called `Logger` in package `logger`, which contained the interface. From right outside the package (and folder), I said:

`mockery -dir logger -name Logger -inpkg logger -testonly`

and the logger was generated, but it was created in the file `mock_Logger.go`.

Comment: This worked for me:
```$ mockery -dir logger -name Logger -inpkg -testonly```

Generating mock for: Logger in file: /tmp/logger/mock_Logger_test.go

Comment: That worked, but now Visual Studio Code won't recognize the mock.

Comment: The problem with the mock when it's defined in the _test.go file is that it's unexported. You can't use it in other packages as well as you can't use it from non-test files like main.go. I think your problem is that you defined Logger interface in the logger package. In most cases you have to define interface in the package where it's being used. So you can define interface in "main" package  while implementation of the logger can reside in "logger" package.